# Receiving a build error after running rails new dearMe

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my first time recieving an error like this. I run rails new appName, and this error occurs after bundle. I believe it has something to do with permissions, but how do I solve this error?

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150930-6103-dzkbp3.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean


Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.



make "DESTDIR="


Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.



make failed, exit code 69

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/byebug-6.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0/byebug-6.0.2/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing byebug (6.0.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install byebug -v '6.0.2'` succeeds before bundling.
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
* bin/rake: spring inserted
* bin/rails: spring inserted
```

Comment: You're getting an Xcode permissions error.  You should open Xcode and accept the licensing agreement to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize its so simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run

```
sudo xcrun cc
```

or open XCode and accept the license in the GUI